# Changing ubuntu to windows xp on netbook

Tags: windows, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Windows XP from Ubuntu via USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12129/how-to-install-windows-xp-from-ubuntu-via-usb)
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I have a problem, because lately I installed ubuntu on my netbook and I decided that it worked faster with Windows XP and I would like to go back to it, but I don't know how to remove ubuntu from my hard drive without an live CD (because I don't have an cd-rom). I tried to find a solution, but I didn't find it anywhere. I would be thankful if somebody could help me.

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/q/12129/35775

Comment: @Daniel How do you intend to install windows XP? Since you have a netbook without CD-drive it'll definitely support USB boot. So just create a bootable USB stick with XP on it and format the Ubuntu partition during XP setup.

Comment: While booting from usb i get the hal.dll error.

Answer (score 0):

you could reinstall windows XP from a usb stick. [Here's how](http://liliputing.com/2008/04/install-windows-xp-on-mini-note-usb.html)