# Trying to install Windows XP; bootmgr is missing

Tags: windows-xp

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04, and I wish to go back to windows XP.  I have all the install files on a USB, but when I go to install it, I get an error that says

> bootmgr is missing, press ctrl alt delete to restart

Any help?

Comment: did windows xp option shown on the grub?

Comment: I'm not sure what grub is, i'm not quite educated when it comes to ubuntu

Comment: when you press the power button(turn on your pc),a list of installed os's will appear.It is called grub menu.

Comment: let me check, one second.

Comment: no, it does not show up there.  when i insert my usb to try to install windows xp, it just goes to the screen where i get the error and i have to take it out and restart my computer to get back to ubuntu.

Comment: you already installed windows xp or not.

Comment: no, im trying to install it, but when i try to thats when i get the error

Comment: You can't install XP via USB.  It's not supported for USB installation boot.  You'll need to put XP onto a CD or DVD, then follow the installation procedure as normal.

Answer (score 0):

--- COMPLETELY EDITED POST following more precise information received about problem

If I understand correctly, after trying Ubuntu, you want to reinstall Windows XP. You were trying to simply copy the contents of the Windows XP Installation medium to a USB drive and got a "BOOTMGR missing" error when trying to start the computer with this USB drive.

My first idea was to replace the boot sector on the USB drive with a Windows XP boot sector, which would try to load NTLDR instead of BOOTMGR. However, this failed to take into account that with either boot sectors (older XP version or updated Vista and newer version) the Windows XP Installation medium is not designed to be started from USB (unlike that of Windows Vista and newer).

From other comments that you made, I seem to understand that you do not own a physical copy of your Windows XP installation medium, but rather have an ISO copy of it.

The logical advice from here is simply to burn your ISO copy to a CD-ROM and to use that disc to start the computer and install Windows XP the way it was designed to be. This solution does not seem to appeal to you. Maybe you don't have a CD-ROM drive or burner in that computer?

Comment: i'm on ubuntu right now, and i have all the correct install files on my usb.  i've been using ubuntu for a couple weeks, and i wish to go back to windows xp, but every time i try to install it over ubuntu and get rid of ubuntu, i get the bootmgr is missing error.  so i would need to get the correct partitions?  what else could i do?

Comment: This error message, when do you get it? When trying to start the Windows installation? Or can you install Windows and then you get this message after the installation when it tries to start Windows for the first time?

Comment: i also formatted my usb with gparted into an ntfs file system

Comment: i cant install windows at all.  right when my computer boots up, it goes to a black screen telling me that im missing the bootmgr, and the only option is to restart and go back to ubuntu

Comment: Which is probably what the problem is: I imagine Gparted created the partition on your USB drive with the newer version of the NTFS boot sector. Don't you have the original Windows XP CD-ROM to start from?

Comment: no, i do not.  how would i be able to get the older boot sectors?  is there any possible way?

Comment: The easiest way is to format your USB drive in another computer running Windows XP. Otherwise, the Windows ADK contains a tool called BOOTSECT.EXE which allows you to change the boot sector (but it seems a bit overkill to download this huge package for just this tiny tool). And again, once you have the correct boot sector, I am not even sure this will allow you to start the Windows XP installation!

Comment: A quick search for "can windows xp cd-rom be copied and started from a usb drive" seems to show that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

- Winusb doesn't support windows xp.so follow the simple steps given below,
- Download [*multiboot*](http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2),and then follow [*this*](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) guide to make bootable windows usb.
- Already tested Windows XP, Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Comment: i've tried using winusb before, but i still got the same error message after it was done.  i'll try it again though and give you the results.

Comment: format the usb to fat32 filesystem and then make bootable windows usb through winusb.

Comment: okay, i will do that now.  i'll give you the results in a bit.

Comment: still getting the same error, but it now shows "winusb -- loading" at the top of the blacks screen.

Comment: what are the files inside usb?Did you boot from the usb(changing boot-order in bios)

Comment: boot
DOCS
DOTNETFX
I386
OEM
$OEM$
SUPPORT
VALUEADD
AUTORUN.INF
README.HTM
SETUP.EXE
SETUPXP.HTM
WIN51
WIN51IP
WIN51IP.SP3

Comment: and yes the boot order in bios is set to boot from the usb

Comment: pls list out the file and folder names in pastebin.com and post the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SjQTjekf

Comment: trying this now, ill get back to you in a bit

Comment: now i'm getting an error that says unknown filesystem in the place where the other error was, but the other error is gone.

Comment: did you format the usb to fat32 filesystem?.And then follow the multiboot guide.

Comment: yes, i followed the guide and did everything exactly as it said.

Comment: check your iso file,is that corrupted or not.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it isnt corrupted.  i did exactly as the guide says, formatted into fat32, then added the iso onto the usb with the program.  i start my computer and it instantly goes to a black screen where it says "unknown filesystem" then says something that has to do with grub.

Comment: did you change the boot-order in bios?

Comment: right now the usb is first in the boot order of my bios

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/12129/how-to-install-windows-xp-from-ubuntu-via-usb

Comment: i've already tried that and it still didn't work.  looks like im stuck on ubuntu for now :\ thanks for the help though.